# Splitting a full name field into first and last name

Tags: string, coldfusion

I have a form with a full-name text field and I would like to break the string into a first and last name strings... I'm handling the form in Coldufusion.

What is the most reliable way to achieve this? I'm assuming JavaScript is not an option since, in its absence, the form would generate an error. Any examples would be great.

Thanks

Comment: For examples of the kind of input you should be prepared to handle, see http://semaphorecorp.com/nc/namechop.html

Comment: Yes ... regardless of the solution you choose for this problem, you should be aware that it rests on a false premise, namely that you can accurately identify first and last name in all cases. Using split() or listFirst()/listRest is a solid starting point, but you'll need to clean up cases where the split was not accurate. (This is an excellent reason to design a form with separate fields for first and last names, or whatever name fields you wish to collect. The user will invariably split his or her name better than you could.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found a better solution

```
<cfset fullName = "foo bar">
<cfset firstName = listFirst(fullName, " ")>
<cfset lastName = listRest(fullName, " ")>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to split on the first space, you can use the list functions.  For example, you could get the first word by using

```
<cfset first = listfirst(fullname, " ")>
```

List functions all take an optional parameter, delimiters, which lets you specify how the list is delimited.  So, in this case, your list is space-delimited.

Remember that not all names are two words.  People use middle names, constructs like "De Marco" and "Van DeGraff" and so forth, or multiple first names like "Lisa Ann".  But this will get you a good approximation.

Comment: Ben, is it possible to <cfset firstName = listfirst(fullName, " ")> and then subtract it from fullName... thus ending up with the first word as firstName and the rest of the sentence as lastName?

Comment: <cfset lastname = trim(replace(fullname, firstname, "")) /> Think I've got the arguments in the right order... replace the firstname found in fullname with nothing and then trim to remove the otherwise leading space.

Answer (score 0):

In coldfusion, after it is submitted, I would split it on a space character.

Comment: Do you know the function for doing such a thing, Jippen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetToken(fullname,1) and getToken(fullName,2)