# Regular Expression to Extract Surnames With Prefixes

Tags: regex, preg-match, names

Is there a way I can extract parts of a name from a string, using regular expression or other logic.

I would like to split names by spaces, but in the case that a name is prefixed, I would like to split on the prefix, e.g.

```
Osama bin Laden bin Mohammed => Osama, bin Laden, bin Mohamed
Jorge do Pinto da Silva => Jorge, do Pinto, da Silva
John Andrew Smith => John, Andrew, Smith
José Mário dos Santos Mourinho Félix => José, Mário, dos Santos, Mourinho, Félix
```

***Working code based on Tim's suggestion***:

```
$str = 'Manuel D\'Souza do Pinto bin Laden Al-saud el Mecca de la Vere Na Sokakah van Der Reidejin del Monte du Pont ter Johannes';
preg_match_all( '~\b(von der|van de|van den|del la|de la|van der|vande|vanden|vander|st|der|des|dela|della|bin|dos|ur|ibn|bint|da|do|le|la|del|du|de|di|el|al|van|von|ter|na|del|san|los)\s+[^\s]+\b|\b[^\s]+~i', $str, $mat );
print_r( $mat );
```

Result:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Manuel
        [1] => D'Souza
        [2] => do Pinto
        [3] => bin Laden
        [4] => Al-saud
        [5] => el Mecca
        [6] => de la Vere
        [7] => Na Sokakah
        [8] => van Der Reidejin
        [9] => del Monte
        [10] => du Pont
        [11] => ter Johannes
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => do
        [3] => bin
        [4] => 
        [5] => el
        [6] => de la
        [7] => Na
        [8] => van Der
        [9] => del
        [10] => du
        [11] => ter
    )
```

)

Comment: No, there is no such way. At least not easily expressed in regex. See [Splitting a person's name into forename and surname](http://stackoverflow.com/q/259634/1048572) and [Heuristics for splitting full names](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15597474/1048572) for discussion.

Comment: What about uppercase prefixes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping in mind all those [falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/), you could still try

```
\b\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*|\b\p{Ll}+\s+\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*
```

will match an uppercase word (name) or a lowercase prefix, followed by an uppercase word.

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/wT1rO6).

**Explanation:**

```
\b      # Start of word
\p{Lu}  # One uppercase letter
\p{Ll}* # Any number of lowercase letters
|       # or
\b      # Start of word
\p{Ll}+ # One or more lowercase letters
\s+     # Whitespace
\p{Lu}  # One uppercase letter
\p{Ll}* # Any number of lowercase letters
```

Comment: Thank you. This is stopping on non-ASSCI characters, but I should be able to make some modifications...

Comment: @KohjahBreese: Did you set the `\u` flag? Otherwise, `\b` won't be Unicode-aware. Or did you mean it stops on non-letters (apostrophes etc.)?

Comment: No. I will have a look at that now. I have added the snipped that does what I want in the op.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is about using splitting. here is one regex that should work:

```
$re = '/\b(?<!-)(?>\p{Ll}+|\p{L}{1,3}) +(*SKIP)(*FAIL)| +/u';
$str = 'Manuel D\'Souza do Pinto bin Laden Al-saud el Mecca de la Vere Na Sokakah van Der Reidejin del Monte du Pont ter Johannes';
print_r( preg_split($re, $str) );
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Manuel
    [1] => D'Souza
    [2] => do Pinto
    [3] => bin Laden
    [4] => Al-saud
    [5] => el Mecca
    [6] => de la Vere
    [7] => Na Sokakah
    [8] => van Der Reidejin
    [9] => del Monte
    [10] => du Pont
    [11] => ter Johannes
)
```

- `(*FAIL)` behaves like a failing negative assertion and is a synonym for `(?!)`
- `(*SKIP)` defines a point beyond which the regex engine is not allowed to backtrack when the subpattern fails later
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` together provide an alternative of restriction that you cannot have a variable length lookbehinf in above regex.

Comment: Thank you for the contribution. I was not aware of these rules. However, it is required that it pick up upper and lower case prefixes, e.g. 'De La Vere' and 'de la vere.'

Comment: Are you getting your desired output from other answers?

Comment: No, but I am from the code I posted at the end of my answer based on one of the suggestions. I see that is not very clear so will edit it.

Comment: It will also help if you show your expected output in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
[a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+
```

The above will match those. So you don't need to split. Just match them.

What it is doing is, it looks for small cased word plus space and then the name or the name alone.

Also note that it will fail on different accents other than English.

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/bY8oT1)

Comment: I did not downvote it. I voted it up for you. This may work, but I need something that will match characters from and Unicode block, like Cyrillic. I will play around with this and the above.

Comment: @KohjahBreese, that is difficult, I suppose

Comment: Yes. I think something that would be largely accurate will probably involve a lot of code.